# Make ADO generate parameters for a temporary stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, vba, vb6, ado

I'm trying to get ADO to recognize parameters from a stored procedure on SQL Sever. If I do this with a normal stored procedure, it works fine:

```
conn.Execute "create proc NormalSP (@i int output) as set @i = 3"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "NormalSP"
cmd.Parameters.Refresh 'parameters list now has @RETURN_VALUE and @i
cmd.Execute
Debug.Print cmd("@i")
```

But if I try the same thing with a temporary stored procedure, it can't get the parameters:

```
conn.Execute "create proc #TempSP (@i int output) as set @i = 3"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "#TempSP"
cmd.Parameters.Refresh 'parameters list remains empty
cmd.Execute 'error: command expects parameter '@i', which was not supplied
Debug.Print cmd("@i") 'error: item cannot be found in the collection
```

What more do I need to get `Parameters.Refresh` to work with a temp SP as it does with a normal SP?

Comment: Are conn and cmd both using the same connection?  A temporary object is deleted once the connection using it is closed.

Comment: Yes, and I can execute the SP if I add in all the parameters manually. It's just that `Parameters.Refresh` isn't finding them.

Comment: Intriguing question, but why would you need to discover parameters of a stored procedure that your client just created? Assuming the .Refresh method won't work: what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Asking two black boxes (legacy ADO, the OLEDB/ODBC provider) why they don't like your interpretation of what context should expose is not likely to provide a very satisfactory answer, but since the original intent is unclear...

Assuming you can accept a short-lived, global temporary stored procedure to ask it for temporary parameters (and in contradiction to what is presumably your downvote above), just connect to the right db in the first place:

**Complete, repeat-safe sample** (using SQL 2012 native client):

```
Public Sub DoITemporarilyHaveParametersForADO()

    Dim conn    As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd     As ADODB.Command
    Dim prm     As ADODB.Parameter

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=(local);Database=tempdb;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    conn.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    conn.Open

    conn.Execute "IF OBJECT_ID('TempSP') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC TempSP"
    conn.Execute "create proc TempSP (@i int output) as set @i = 3;"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "TempSP"
    cmd.Parameters.Refresh
    For Each prm In cmd.Parameters
        Debug.Print prm.Name & ": " & prm.Value
    Next prm
    Debug.Print "cmd.Parameters.Count: " & cmd.Parameters.Count
    cmd.Execute
    Debug.Print cmd("@i")

    conn.Execute "IF OBJECT_ID('TempSP') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC TempSP"
    conn.Close

    Set prm = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Immediate Window output**:

```
@RETURN_VALUE: 
@i: 
cmd.Parameters.Count: 2
 3
```

**Some useful [clarification from MSFT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**:

> Temporary stored procedures are useful when connecting to earlier
>   versions of SQL Server that do not support the reuse of execution
>   plans for Transact-SQL statements or batches. Applications connecting
>   to SQL Server 2000 and higher should use the sp_executesql system
>   stored procedure instead of temporary stored procedures.

....

> If a stored procedure not prefixed with # or ## is created directly in
>   the tempdb database, the stored procedure is automatically deleted
>   when SQL Server is shut down because tempdb is re-created every time
>   SQL Server is started. Procedures created directly in tempdb exist
>   even after the creating connection is terminated.

Meaning of course that if you throw a breakpoint into that VBA sample round about line 27, flip over to SSMS, connect to `(local)`, switch to `tempdb`, and `EXEC TempSP`, you will be told

> Procedure or function 'TempSP' expects parameter '@i', which was not
>   supplied.

instead of

> Could not find stored procedure 'TempSP'.

before and after sample execution.

Comment: I don't have permissions to make a normal SP in tempdb. If I did then I would just do that, since normal SPs are already known to work.

Comment: @rdhs An SP created without the hash symbols, but directly in the tempdb is not "normal", as the MSFT quote directly states. It is a global temporary SP. And perhaps you should have stated your restrictions (along with your intentions) up front. This answer directly and thoroughly addresses your question.

Comment: Good for you, I'm sure you must be very proud.

Comment: @rdhs SO should grant you the Bad Attitude badge

Comment: The question specifically asked: "if I try the same thing with a temporary stored procedure", so, it's a thin line here ;-)

Comment: @mceda Which is why the answer specifically states "Assuming you can accept a short-lived, global temporary stored procedure..." When the OP isn't clear, the line isn't fine, it's invisible, it's red, and it's in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it a global temporary SP:

```
conn.Execute "create proc ##TempSP (@i int output) as set @i = 3"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "##TempSP"
cmd.Parameters.Refresh 'parameters list remains empty
cmd.Execute
Debug.Print cmd("@i")
```

Comment: If it's a global SP, the parameters list still comes back empty.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure but I thought it was worth a shot.  I don't have any other ideas

Answer (score 0):

Put `cmd.Parameters(1).Value = intYourValue`
before `cmd.Execute`